# Scrapy: RSS control pub_date

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm doing a RSS spider. How do you do for controlling the last crawl
date?

Right now what was I thinking is this:

- Put in a control file the last pub_date that I have crawled.
- Then when the crawl starts, it checks the last pub_date against the
  new pub_dates. If there are new items, then start crawling, if not, do
  nothing.

How does everyone else resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I store all data in the database (including last crawl date and post dates) and take all dates I need from database.

Answer (score 0):

I store all data in database as well, and calculate a hash value out of the data. That way you can look up the hash very quickly, and carry out de-dup operation on the fly.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you do this?